# Direction Field & Phase Portrait of A System of Two First Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab, mathematica

I need to plot a direction field and phase portrait of system of two first order differential equation using a computer (AKA program like Mathematica, Matlab, etc)

Does anyone know what kind of code I would need to use for this? We were told to come in with the direction fields and phase portraits, but we weren't told how to do it. :/

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your system of odes?

Comment: At least Matlab or Mathematica have special sections of Tutorial/Help to cover this topic. In Matlab this command is called `quiver`.